# Is there a way to trace backwards on an XML tree using xmllint?

Tags: xml, bash, xmllint

Currently working on a project using Bash that parses an XML file. For example if I have bookstore.xml:

```
<bookstore>
    <genre name = "Childrens">
       <book>
           <author>
           <title name = "Cat in the Hat">
       </book>
    </genre/
    <genre name = "Young Adult">
       <book>
           <author>
           <title name = "Twilight">
       </book>
    </genre>
</bookstore>
...
```

Given that I am already able to extract all of the </title/> names from the xml file. I am now trying to use a given </title/> and somehow trace backwards and find its respective </genre/> and somehow map the </title/> of the book to the </genre/> using an associative array. For example:

```
books[$title] = $genre
books["Cat in the Hat"] = "Childrens"
```

The first step, I believe, is to retrieve that genre name knowing that I already have the </titles/> saved in a separate array. My goal in the end is to essentially compare a separate xml file that contains only book titles and compare it to bookstore.xml. When I run the program and compare it to bookstore.xml, the program will read all the times in the input file and return the genre for each title. For another reference, here is how I am able to extract the titles from a given bookstore.xml file and what *I'm trying* to accomplish.

```
TITLES=$(echo 'cat //title/@name' | xmllint --shell $filename | sed -n 's: name=\"\(.*\)\":\1:p') 

for title in $TITLES; do
      BOOKS[$title]="[this will be its respective genre somehow]"
done
```

In the end, if I input an xml file with only titles and compare it to bookstore.xml, the output should look something like:

```
Title: Cat in the Hat Genre: Children's
Title: Twilight Genre: Young Adult
```

Please help with this and let me know if any further clarification is needed! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason that you're using bash to do this rather than an xml parser?

Comment: It's supposed to be a quick tool just ran from the command line when needed.

Comment: Can you edit your question and first, make sure your xml is valid and, second, show your exact expected output from your sample xml?

Comment: Hi @JackFleeting, I updated the post and added more information on what I am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply go through the file from the "bottom-up" as it were, it might be nice to just read through it from the end. I've written up a quick example (with admittedly terrible runtime) that should do what you want provided your files aren't insanely large:

```bash
for (( idx=0; idx<${#TITLES[@]}; idx++ )); do
    flag=0

    tac $filename | while IFS= read line; do
        # found the entry, go up until we find the genre
        if [[ $line  == *"${TITLES[$idx]}"* ]]; then
            flag=1
        fi

        if [[ $flag == 1 ]] && [[ $line == *"<genre"* ]]; then
            # trim the line so that it only contains the quoted material:
            genre=${line#*\"}
            genre=${genre%*\">}

            title=${TITLES[$idx]}
            BOOKS[$title] = $genre
            break
        fi
    done
done
```

If you don't have tac, you can use this instead (both examples were taken from this   [post](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/263568-script-bash-read-file-line-per-line-starting-end.html) on https://www.unix.com):

```bash
perl -e 'print reverse <>' $filename | while IFS= read line; do
    # rest of code in here
done
```

Comment: Thank you for this example. The files that I am dealing are pretty large so although this could be helpful for smaller files, I don't think it would be efficient to do the entire job I am looking for. However I appreciate your input and will still consider the ideas you've given.

Answer (score 0):

To get the titles and genres into variables, use:

```
titles=$(xmllint --xpath //genre/book/title/@name  file.xml)
```

and

```
names=$(xmllint --xpath //genre/@name  file.xml)
```

If you can use xmlstarlet instead, it's simpler and you don't need to use variables:

```
xmlstarlet select -T -t -m //genre -v " concat('Title: ',book/title/@name, ' ','Genre: ',@name)" -n file.xml
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. But I only have xmllint, xpath is not supported, I forgot to clarify that. But how do I make sure, given a title name, that it will return its correct genre?

Comment: @Mel xmllint does support a limited subset of xpath 1.0, so the answer should work (it worked for me). Try it on your xml and let me know.

Comment: I get an error when I try your command: "Unknown option --xpath"

Comment: @Mel Don't know why you get the error. xpath is an option for xmllint: https://softwaretester.info/test-xml-command-line-with-xmllint/

Comment: I'm not sure why either. So I have been searching for a solution that does not use xpath because it has not been working for me.

Comment: @Mel You can't use anything other then `xmllint`?

Comment: I am working on updating my software version that supports --xpath. For now, I only have xmllint. @Reino